# Ansible "gcp_compute_instance" module won't assign External IP to VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

```
- name: Create Disk
  gcp_compute_disk:
    name: "{{app_name}}-disk"
    size_gb: 50
    source_image: "{{source_image}}"
    zone: "{{ gcp_zone }}"
    project: web-project
    auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
    state: present
  register: disk

- name: Reserve IP Address
  gcp_compute_address:
    name: "{{app_name}}-address"
    region: "{{region}}"
    project: vpc-project
    auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
    state: present
  register: address

- name: Create VM Instance
  gcp_compute_instance:
    name: "{{app_name}}-vm"
    machine_type: "{{instance_type}}"
    disks:
    - auto_delete: true
      boot: true
      source: "{{disk}}"
    network_interfaces:
    - subnetwork: 
        selfLink: "{{subnetwork}}"
        access_configs:
        - name: External NAT
          nat_ip: "{{ address }}"
          type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
    zone: "{{ gcp_zone }}"
    project: web-project
    auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
    state: present
  register: instance
```

The VPC exists in the "vpc-project" and is shared with "web-project", which has no network of its own.

Region: us-west1
Zone: us-west1-b

When I run the code, it successfully creates the VM using the other projects VPC and assigns an internal IP to it.

However, it does NOT assign the external IP to it. I have confirmed that the address was created and in the correct region, but it's just sitting there unused.

Just for testing, I had it create an external address and a VM in the projects local network but it still didn't assign the public address to it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to reserve a static IP address in one project and use that in another project? If yes, you cannot do that. Also, compute engine IP addresses are regional. The reserved IP address and VM instance must be in the same region. Edit your question and include details on Project IDs (masked), regions, and zones so that we know what you are trying to configure.

Comment: While the VM lives in the "web-project", it's network interface is using the Shared VPC from "vpc-project". The external IP is being reserved in "vpc-project" because I want to use it in the network that lives there. It's not technically going to another project. Everything is in us-west1, including the regional IP.

Comment: External IPs are not associated to a VPC so external IPs are not shared through this. External IPs should be reserved in the project where the VM lives so we can focus on why IPs in the same project are not associated. What value are you setting here `nat_ip: "{{ address }}"`?

Answer (score 1):

John and Ferregina were correct - an external IP from one project cannot be assigned to a resource in another project. I changed the playbook accordingly.

However that was not the cause of my pain. It was a playbook-related issue. Using the "selfLink" in the play was causing it to completely ignore the entire part about "access_configs" for some reason.

I changed it from this:

```
network_interfaces:
- subnetwork: 
    selfLink: "{{subnetwork}}"
    access_configs:
    - name: External NAT
      nat_ip: "{{ address }}"
      type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

To this:

```
network_interfaces:
- subnetwork: "{{subnetwork_info.resources[0]}}"
  access_configs:
  - name: External NAT
    nat_ip: "{{ external_address }}"
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

And it worked.